# PHP ignorando if e dando ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, redirecionamento-de-url

Olá, desenvolvo um programa para a loja que trabalho e quando mandamos abrir um cupom, ele faz a verificação para ver se está abrindo um cupom já existente(com a variável `$_GET['cupom']`) ou se é um cupom novo. Funcionava muito bem, inclusive existia até um `if` com redirecionamento a mais nesse código antes da última atualização, nunca havia dado erro de Vários Redirecionamentos mas agora está dando não sei porque.

Quando o navegador exibe a tela de erro com o ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, a url exibida é `http://localhost/administrar/pedidos_venda.php?cupom=1&aberto=1` como se o `else if(!$existeCodigoCupom)` foi executado. Mas se for verdade, o programa ignorou os `if`'s anteriores.

Aprendi tudo o que sei sozinho, por documentações e fóruns. Pode ser que possua erros, sintam-se a vontade para indicar, assim aprendo um pouco mais.

Segue o código php:

```php
if(!isset($_GET['cupom']))
{

    $existeCodigoCupom = DBRead("vendapedidos", "ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $codigoCupom = DBRead("vendapedidos" , "WHERE status = '-1' AND aberto = '0' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");

    if($codigoCupom)
    {
        if($codigoCupom[0]['aberto'] == 0)
        {
            $codigo = $codigoCupom[0]['id'];

            $dados = array
            (
                'dataHoraCriacao' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'dataHoraAtualizacao' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'valores' => "0,,0",
                'status' => -1
            );

            $registraCupom = DBUpDate("vendapedidos", $dados, "id = '{$codigo}'");
            if($registraCupom)
            {
                header('Location: /administrar/pedidos_venda.php?cupom='.$codigo);
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Não foi possível abrir o cupom!";
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
    else if($existeCodigoCupom)
    {
        $codigo = $codigoCupom[0]['id'];
        $codigo++;

        $dados = array
        (
            'dataHoraCriacao' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'dataHoraAtualizacao' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'valores' => "0,,0",
            'status' => -1
        );

        $registraCupom = DBCreate("vendapedidos", $dados);
        if($registraCupom)
        {
            header('Location: /administrar/pedidos_venda.php?cupom='.$codigo);
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Não foi possível abrir o cupom!";
            exit();
        }
    }
    else if(!$existeCodigoCupom)
    {
        $codigo = 1;

        $dados = array
        (
            'dataHoraCriacao' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'dataHoraAtualizacao' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'valores' => "0,,0",
            'status' => -1
        );

        $registraCupom = DBCreate("vendapedidos", $dados);
        if($registraCupom)
        {
            header('Location: /administrar/pedidos_venda.php?cupom='.$codigo);
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Não foi possível abrir o cupom!";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: De um `print_r` em `$existeCodigoCupom` e `$codigoCupom`, mostre-me o resultado disso!

Comment: A função `DBRead` faz leitura no banco de dandos, está retornando array com os resultados, acredito que os valores não irão influenciar aqui, se quiser envio em outro comentário, então vou tentar explica-las. A variável `$existeCodigoCupom` verifica se algum valor é retornado, sendo assim já existe um cupom salvo no banco e `$codigoCupom` faz uma busca no banco verificando se há cupom com o `status = '-1'` que são cupons que foram abertos mas não tiveram um cliente atribuído, para assim reaproveitar o cupom.

Comment: Para esclarecer, se eu retorno e tento abrir a página novamente, a página funciona normalmente

Comment: coloca no comentário @TúlioMoreira, o var_dump($existeCodigoCupom), precisamos saber o que vem nesta variável para conseguir te ajudar melhor. Abraço

Comment: valor impresso para `$existeCodigoCupom`: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 30 [cobranca] => [dataHoraCriacao] => 2019-08-16 17:42:47 [dataHoraAtualizacao] => 2019-08-16 17:42:47 [idCliente] => 0 [cliente] => [endereco] => [bairro] => [cidade] => [estado] => [telefone] => [produtos] => [valores] => 0,,0 [status] => -1 [aberto] => 0 ) )`